# WeakMap polyfill throwing error when trying to define property on inextensible object

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

The [WeakMap polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/blob/master/src/WeakMap/WeakMap.js) is throwing an error when trying to define property on inextensible object.
Those are in the middle of a bunch of node, javascript code and libraries so I couldn't actually point out where causes the issue. There are many other libraries which also have their own polyfill. It's difficult to debug in which library causes the error. And, the errors are ONLY on IE10.
To get rid of it, I added a checker before defining a property like (line 26 in the above file):

```
if (entry && entry[0] === key) {
    entry[1] = value;
}
else if (Object.isExtensible(key)) {
    defineProperty(key, this.name, {
        value: [ key, value ],
        writable: true
    }); 
}
```

My question is, Is it safe/right to fix it as in my code above? If not, how should I fix my problem?

Comment: What type of object is giving you the problem in IE10?  Perhaps there is a work-around for the extensibility of that type of object.

Comment: It's so difficult to know. There are many packages in 1 system and each of them has different polyfill. They might overlap each other.

Answer (score 1):

As best I can tell that `weakMap` polyfill is ONLY designed to work with extensible objects as keys.  It simply won't work with a non-extensible object.

Your modification has made it so it doesn't throw an exception, but then the non-extensible item will not be in the `weakMap` either.  So, your fix isn't really a fix.  That particular polyfill would have to be rewritten to handle non-extensible keys.  It would not be a simple fix as it would need a conceptually different approach.

There are a number of other polyfills that take a different approach.  I have not researched which ones might be better in this regard.  I suspect it's a little bit of conundrum between actually being "weak" (e.g. allows garbage collection) vs. can handle a non-extensible object.  The fundamental issue is that if you are going to be weak, then you can't store a reference to the object itself.  So, you need to store a reference to some string representation of the object.  Well, JS objects don't have a built-in guaranteed unique string representation.  So, the usually fix is to coin one using some sort of counter and store it on the object as a property and then you store that string representation in your map.  But, if the object isn't extensible, then you can't do that either.  So, you're stuck storing the actual object reference in your map, but then it's not really "weak" any more.  You can see how you're kind of stuck.

I think this is one case where a polyfill just can't quite live up to the real thing.  Different polyfills will have different tradeoffs in this regard.  You picked one that is truly weak, but requires the objects to be extensible so a property can be added.

Comment: @CygnusKnight - Did this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  If not, then please explain what you still need help with.

Answer (score 0):

As in my question, I want a solution which does not have huge impact on other functionality or plugins, so here is my fix for this issue. The fix is based on the answer of @jfriend00 above and reference from other implementation in the internet.

```
var defineProperty = Object.defineProperty;
var counter = Date.now() % 1e9;
var FrozenStore = function() {
    this.a = [];
};
var findFrozen = function(store, key){
    return store.a.forEach(function(it){
        if (it[0] === key) {
            return it;
        }
    });
};
var findIndexFrozen = function(store, key){
    return store.a.forEach(function(it, id){
        if (it[0] === key) {
            return id;
        }
    });
};
FrozenStore.prototype = {
    get: function(key){
        var entry = findFrozen(this, key);
        if (entry) return entry[1];
    },
    has: function(key){
        return !!findFrozen(this, key);
    },
    set: function(key, value){
        var entry = findFrozen(this, key);
        if (entry) entry[1] = value;
        else this.a.push([key, value]);
    },
    "delete": function(key){
        var index = findIndexFrozen(this, key);
        if (~index) this.a.splice(index, 1);
        return !!~index;
    }
};
var WeakMap = function() {
    this.name = "__st" + (Math.random() * 1e9 >>> 0) + (counter++ + "__");
};
var frozenStore = function(that){
    return that._l || (that._l = new FrozenStore);
};
WeakMap.prototype = {
    set: function(key, value) {
        var entry = key[this.name];
        if (entry && entry[0] === key) {
            entry[1] = value;
        } else {
            if (!Object.isExtensible(key)) {
                frozenStore(this).set(key, value);
            } else {
                defineProperty(key, this.name, {
                    value: [ key, value ],
                    writable: true
                });
            }
        }
        return this;
    },
    get: function(key) {
        var entry;
        if ((entry = key[this.name]) && entry[0] === key) {
            return entry[1];
        } else if (!Object.isExtensible(key)) {
            frozenStore(this).get(key);
        } else {
            return undefined;
        }
    },
    "delete": function(key) {
        var entry = key[this.name];
        if (!entry || entry[0] !== key) return false;
        if (!Object.isExtensible(key)) frozenStore(this)['delete'](key);
        entry[0] = entry[1] = undefined;
        return true;
    },
    has: function(key) {
        var entry = key[this.name];
        if (!entry) return false;
        if(!Object.isExtensible(key)) return frozenStore(this).has(key);
        return entry[0] === key;
    }
};
window.WeakMap = WeakMap;
```

This introduces the FrozenStore which will manage all non-extensible keys being added to WeakMap. I'm not sure whether it breaks the concept of WeakMap or not but it does rescue me from the issue.